# Default TFS Windows Accounts+Permissions when installed on a Windows Server that is joined to a domain

Tags: tfs

After DCpromoing and then demoting the server that TFS runs on, we cannot use WSS ("Cannot connect to the configuration database") to manage team projects. I believe that if I could find the default permissions that are set up when TFS is first installed on a server that is joined to a domain - in terms of any service accounts that are created and which accounts various services should run as - I would be able to get it back up and running again. Does anybody know the default NT accounts and permissions for Team Foundation Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error sounds like a SharePoint error. This [technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863%28office.12%29.aspx) outlines the permissions (server, SQL, registry) that are required for a default WSS install.